# toUIntMax() and toIntMax() removed from Swift 4

Tags: swift, int, facebook-ios-sdk, swift4

[image]

What has replaced the method toUIntMax() and the method toIntMax() in Swift 4 ? The error occurred within the FacebookCore framework.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The concept of `IntMax` has been completely removed as part of [SE-104](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0104-improved-integers.md).

> Converting from one integer type to another is performed using the concept of the 'maximum width integer' (see `MaxInt`), which is an artificial limitation. The very existence of `MaxInt` makes it unclear what to do should someone implement `Int256`, for example.

> The proposed model eliminates the 'largest integer type' concept previously used to interoperate between integer types (see `toIntMax` in the current model) and instead provides access to machine words. It also introduces the `multipliedFullWidth(by:)`, `dividingFullWidth(_:)`, and `quotientAndRemainder` methods. Together these changes can be used to provide an efficient implementation of bignums that would be hard to achieve otherwise.

In this specific case FB SDK should simply use the `UInt64($0)` initializer which is now available for any `BinaryInteger` type thanks to the new protocols.

Answer (score 1):

You can also for now, can select Swift 3.2 under Pods -> Targets -> ObjectMapper -> Swift language version option